# Problems With JQuery Select Validation

Tags: jquery

Hello I'm quite new to JQuery & I'm having trouble getting the validation to work proper with a contact form tutorial i followed that did not include a select box.

Here is the JQuery code:

```
$(".txtbar, .txtbox").live("focus", function () {
    var thelabel = $(this).prev();
    var infobox = $(this).next();
    var rowbox = $(this).parent();
    var currid = $(this).attr('id');
    var pxlchange = '-145px';

    if (currid == "contactnumber") {
        pxlchange = '-145px';
    }
    if (currid == "message") {
        pxlchange = '-145px';
    }

    rowbox.addClass('colors');


    thelabel.animate({
        left: pxlchange
    }, 350, 'linear', function () {
        // animation complete
    });

    infobox.animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, 350, 'linear', function () {
        // animation complete
    });


    $(this).live("keyup", function () {
        var theval = $(this).val();
        var value = $("subject").val();
        var limitval = 3;
        var replacehtml = "";
        var nameinfohtml = "Not a valid Name!";
        var emailinfohtml = "Not a valid E-mail address!";
        var contactnumberinfohtml = "This field is optional!";
        var subjectinfohtml = "Not a valid subject!";
        var messageinfohtml = "Please fill this field out!";


        if (currid == "name") {
            replacehtml = nameinfohtml;
        } else if (currid == "email") {
            replacehtml = emailinfohtml;
        } else if (currid == "contactnumber") {
            replacehtml = contactnumberinfohtml;
            limitval = 9;
        } else if (value == '0') {
            replacehtml = subjectinfohtml;

        } else if (currid == "message") {
            replacehtml = messageinfohtml;
            limitval = 10;
        }



        // checking against e-mail regex
        if (currid == "email") {
            if (checkValidEmailAddress(theval)) {
                infobox.html("Accepted!");
                infobox.addClass('good');
            } else if (!checkValidEmailAddress(theval)) {
                infobox.html(replacehtml);
                infobox.removeClass('good');
            }
        } else {
            // we use this logic to check for name+message fields
            if (theval.length >= limitval) {
                infobox.html("Accepted!");
                infobox.addClass('good');
            } else if (theval.length < limitval) {
                infobox.html(replacehtml);
                infobox.removeClass('good');
            }                
       // we use this logic to check the subject
            if (value.val() !== '0') {
                infobox.html("Accepted!");
                infobox.addClass('good');
            } else if (value.val() == '0') {
                infobox.html(replacehtml);
                infobox.removeClass('good');
            }
        }


        // now we check if we can display the send button
        // much easier to just look for 'good class on the req fields
        if ($('#name').next().hasClass('good') && $('#email').next().hasClass('good') && $('#message').next().hasClass('good')) {
            // if all 3 boxes are good then we display our send button!
            // jquery validation complete
            $('#sendbtn').animate({
                opacity: 1.0
            }, 200, 'linear', function () {
                // display submitbtn animation complete
            });
        }
    });
});

$(".txtbar, .txtbox").live("blur", function () {
    var thelabel = $(this).prev();
    var infobox = $(this).next();
    var rowbox = $(this).parent();
    var currid = $(this).attr('id');

    rowbox.removeClass('colors');

    infobox.animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 400, 'linear', function () {
        // animation complete
    });
});
```

[Here is my JSfiddle attempt at making it work.](http://jsfiddle.net/42ZFZ/1/)

Basically im just trying to get it to find the value "0" and add a class of "good" so it will read the accept message when u pick a subject, I have read a lot of ways how to do this but im not quite sure how to incorporate it this script.

thank you for your time all help is very much appreciated.

Comment: hope you didn't close the problem in your mind. since your real problem is your `value` never be used correctly . the `Accepted` add to select is handled by this code `if (theval.length >= limitval) {     infobox.html("Accepted!"); infobox.addClass('good'); } `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

- `var value = $("subject").val();` should be: `var value = $("#subject").val();`
- `$(this).live("keyup", function () {` should be: `$(this).live("keyup change", function () {`

That should solve your problem, it worked for me.

Here is the jsFiddle I modified: http://jsfiddle.net/MpTbT/

Comment: Your jsfiddle was not updated. But i tried what you suggested and got it to work.. cant believe it was that simple appreciate it! thank you Joshua

Comment: not a problem, glad i could help! the `keyup` event wasn't getting fired because that's a keyboard action while the `select` requires a sort of selection action. `change` is called on a text box when your cursor moves out of the box, and is called on a select when you click on an option.

Comment: thank you for you knowledge and help :) i was completely looking in the wrong area.. Now to try on a registration form.

Comment: @user2499178 although your problem seems been solved, I still insist on the `value.val() !== '0'` problem. if you add a `console.log(value.val())` before your `if else` about `value.val()`, you will get an error. it still seems work just because `theval.length >= limitval` make it work. your code about `value` never do the real work. if you don't believe, try remove the `if else` about `value.val()`, it will still do the work you want.

Comment: @user2499178 and your `var value = $("subject").val();` doesn't cause a problem for the same reason: it never do real work.

Comment: as i said about the value.val() !== '0' i was mucking around i have change it back to (value !== '0'). thanks for your advice though

Answer (score 1):

the `$("subject").val();` should be `$("#subject").val();`

you have to add `#` to select with `id` in jquery

EDIT:

and you already assign `var value = $("#subject").val();` , but you call it `if (value.val() !== '0')` later, this will result in undefined. you should call `if (value !== '0') {`

Comment: I dont think the problem lies within $("subject").val; I believe it is when it goes to if (value.val() !== '0') { infobox.html("Accepted!"); infobox.addClass('good'); I did try $("#subject").val; made no difference.

Comment: also have change (value.val() !== '0') that was me attempting just to by pass.. no luck.

Comment: take a look at the JSfiddle and you will see what i mean.

Comment: @user2499178 also need change the `if (value == '0')` and `keyup`, see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/terryleonhart/SfPVU/2/)